# Changing Wordpress PHP to Show Different Menu to Logged In Users

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a membership website on Wordpress and would like to show a different navigation menu to logged in users.

Here is the current PHP code that displays the menu :

```
                <?php /* Our navigation menu. */ ?>
<?php if ( isset ($options['admired_remove_superfish']) &&  ($options['admired_remove_superfish']!="") )
                    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
                else
                    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu','fallback_cb' => 'admired_page_menu'  ) );?>
```

Here's the PHP code that needs to replace that code :

```
<?php
    if ( wp_emember_is_member_logged_in() ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'logged-in-members' ) );
  } else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'normal-visitor-menu' ) );
  }
?>
```

If I just replace the old code, with the newer code it will work, but the formatting is off. I need the Superfish part in the current code, but I'm not sure how to make it work in PHP.

I know this may be a little confusing, but I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

P.S. This is a tutorial from the plugin's site. I've been following it, but I somehow need to keep the Superfish in there. I'm sure not sure how to do it.

http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-membership/show-different-navigation-menu-to-your-members-and-non-members-551

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'menu_class' => 'sf-menu'` will add the  `sf-menu class` for the menu `(<ul class="sf-menu">)` and `super fish` plugin will use this `class` to identify the menu and style will be applied which has been declared in the `super fish` plugin's `css`

```
<?php
    if ( wp_emember_is_member_logged_in() ) {
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'logged-in-members', 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu' ) );
    } else {
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'normal-visitor-menu', 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu' ) );
    }
?>
```

For more [see this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Comment: perfect! Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

Considering the code above, the only thing that is changing is the actual location of the menu. The (existing) code is showing that you want the menu that's in `'theme_location' => 'primary'` where, as you have a hardcoded menu you want to use, and you're selecting it with `'menu' => 'loggged-in-members'` The finished result will be...

```
<?php
    if ( wp_emember_is_member_logged_in() ) {
       wp_nav_menu( 
           array( 
               'container_class' => 'menu-header', 
               'menu' => 'logged-in-members', 
               'menu_class' => 'sf-menu',
               'fallback_cb' => 'admired_page_menu' 
           ) 
       );
    } else {
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'normal-visitor-menu' ) );
    }
```

?>